# Graph with multiple partitions

Tags: graphs-and-networks, partitions

I have an edgelist

```
originalEdgeList = {"K.CC.2" -> "1.OA.5", "K.CC.3" -> "K.CC.7", 
   "K.CC.3" -> "1.NBT.1", "K.CC.4" -> "K.CC.5", "K.CC.4" -> "K.CC.6", 
   "K.CC.5" -> "K.CC.3", "K.CC.5" -> "K.CC.4", "K.CC.6" -> "K.CC.7", 
   "K.CC.7" -> "1.NBT.3", "K.OA.1" -> "K.OA.2", "K.OA.1" -> "K.OA.3", 
   "K.OA.1" -> "K.OA.5", "K.OA.1" -> "4.NF.3a", "K.OA.2" -> "1.OA.1", 
   "K.OA.3" -> "K.OA.4", "K.OA.3" -> "K.OA.5", "K.OA.3" -> "4.NF.3b", 
   "K.OA.4" -> "K.NBT.1", "K.OA.4" -> "1.OA.3", "K.OA.4" -> "1.OA.4", 
   "K.OA.5" -> "K.OA.3", "K.OA.5" -> "1.OA.6", "K.OA.5" -> "1.NBT.4", 
   "K.NBT.1" -> "1.NBT.2", "K.MD.1" -> "K.MD.2", "K.MD.2" -> "K.CC.6",
    "K.MD.2" -> "K.CC.7", "K.MD.2" -> "1.MD.1", "K.G.2" -> "K.G.1", 
   "K.G.2" -> "K.G.4", "K.G.2" -> "K.G.5", "K.G.2" -> "K.G.6", 
   "K.G.3" -> "K.G.1", "K.G.3" -> "K.G.4", "K.G.3" -> "K.G.5", 
   "K.G.4" -> "1.G.1", "K.G.5" -> "1.G.1", "K.G.6" -> "1.G.2", 
   "K.G.6" -> "1.G.3", "1.OA.1" -> "1.OA.2", "1.OA.1" -> "1.OA.8", 
   "1.OA.1" -> "4.NF.3d", "1.OA.3" -> "1.OA.6", "1.OA.3" -> "1.OA.7", 
   "1.OA.3" -> "4.NF.3c", "1.OA.4" -> "1.OA.6", "1.OA.4" -> "1.OA.7", 
   "1.OA.6" -> "1.NBT.4", "1.OA.6" -> "2.OA.2", "1.OA.6" -> "2.NBT.5",
    "1.OA.7" -> "1.OA.8", "1.NBT.1" -> "1.NBT.2", 
   "1.NBT.1" -> "2.NBT.2", "1.NBT.2" -> "1.NBT.1", 
   "1.NBT.2" -> "1.NBT.3", "1.NBT.2" -> "1.NBT.4", 
   "1.NBT.2" -> "1.NBT.6", "1.NBT.2" -> "2.NBT.1", 
   "1.NBT.3" -> "2.NBT.4", "1.NBT.4" -> "2.NBT.7", 
   "1.NBT.5" -> "2.NBT.8", "1.NBT.6" -> "1.NBT.5", 
   "1.NBT.6" -> "2.NBT.7", "1.MD.1" -> "1.MD.2", "1.MD.1" -> "2.MD.2",
    "1.MD.1" -> "2.MD.4", "1.MD.1" -> "2.MD.9", "1.MD.2" -> "2.MD.1", 
   "1.MD.3" -> "2.MD.7", "1.MD.4" -> "2.MD.10", "1.G.1" -> "2.G.1", 
   "1.G.3" -> "2.G.2", "1.G.3" -> "2.G.3", "2.OA.1" -> "2.NBT.5", 
   "2.OA.1" -> "2.MD.5", "2.OA.1" -> "3.OA.8", "2.OA.1" -> "4.OA.2", 
   "2.OA.2" -> "3.NBT.2", "2.OA.3" -> "3.OA.9", "2.OA.4" -> "2.NBT.2",
    "2.OA.4" -> "3.OA.1", "2.NBT.1" -> "2.NBT.2", 
   "2.NBT.1" -> "2.NBT.3", "2.NBT.1" -> "2.NBT.4", 
   "2.NBT.1" -> "2.NBT.5", "2.NBT.1" -> "2.NBT.6", 
   "2.NBT.1" -> "2.NBT.7", "2.NBT.1" -> "2.NBT.8", 
   "2.NBT.1" -> "3.NBT.1", "2.NBT.1" -> "4.NBT.1", 
   "2.NBT.2" -> "2.OA.4", "2.NBT.2" -> "2.NBT.1", 
   "2.NBT.2" -> "3.NBT.1", "2.NBT.3" -> "4.NBT.2", 
   "2.NBT.4" -> "4.NBT.2", "2.NBT.5" -> "2.OA.1", 
   "2.NBT.5" -> "2.NBT.9", "2.NBT.5" -> "3.NBT.2", 
   "2.NBT.7" -> "3.NBT.2", "2.NBT.8" -> "3.NBT.2", 
   "2.NBT.9" -> "3.NBT.2", "2.MD.1" -> "2.MD.3", "2.MD.1" -> "2.MD.4",
    "2.MD.1" -> "2.MD.6", "2.MD.1" -> "3.MD.4", "2.MD.2" -> "2.MD.3", 
   "2.MD.4" -> "2.MD.5", "2.MD.5" -> "2.OA.1", "2.MD.5" -> "2.MD.6", 
   "2.MD.5" -> "3.MD.8", "2.MD.6" -> "3.NF.2a", "2.MD.6" -> "3.MD.1", 
   "2.MD.7" -> "3.MD.1", "2.MD.8" -> "4.NF.6", "2.MD.9" -> "3.MD.4", 
   "2.MD.10" -> "3.MD.3", "2.G.1" -> "3.G.1", "2.G.2" -> "3.OA.1", 
   "2.G.2" -> "3.MD.6", "2.G.2" -> "3.MD.7c", "2.G.2" -> "4.NBT.5", 
   "2.G.3" -> "3.G.2", "3.OA.1" -> "3.OA.3", "3.OA.1" -> "3.OA.4", 
   "3.OA.1" -> "3.OA.5", "3.OA.1" -> "3.OA.7", "3.OA.1" -> "3.MD.7a", 
   "3.OA.1" -> "4.NBT.5", "3.OA.1" -> "4.NF.4a", "3.OA.2" -> "3.OA.3",
    "3.OA.2" -> "3.OA.4", "3.OA.2" -> "3.OA.5", "3.OA.2" -> "3.OA.6", 
   "3.OA.2" -> "3.OA.8", "3.OA.2" -> "4.NBT.6", "3.OA.3" -> "4.NF.4c",
    "3.OA.5" -> "6.EE.3", "3.OA.7" -> "4.OA.4", "3.OA.7" -> "4.NBT.5",
    "3.OA.8" -> "4.OA.3", "3.OA.9" -> "4.OA.5", 
   "3.NBT.1" -> "4.NBT.3", "3.NBT.2" -> "4.NBT.4", 
   "3.NBT.3" -> "4.NBT.5", "3.NBT.3" -> "4.NBT.6", 
   "3.NF.1" -> "3.NF.2a", "3.NF.1" -> "3.MD.4", "3.NF.2" -> "6.NS.6a",
    "3.NF.2a" -> "3.NF.2b", "3.NF.2b" -> "3.NF.3a", 
   "3.NF.2b" -> "3.NF.3c", "3.NF.3a" -> "3.NF.3b", 
   "3.NF.3a" -> "3.NF.3d", "3.NF.3b" -> "4.NF.1", 
   "3.NF.3b" -> "4.NF.5", "3.NF.3d" -> "4.NF.2", 
   "3.NF.3d" -> "4.NF.5", "3.NF.3d" -> "4.NF.7", "3.MD.1" -> "4.MD.1",
    "3.MD.2" -> "5.MD.3a", "3.MD.4" -> "4.MD.4", 
   "3.MD.5.a" -> "3.MD.5.b", "3.MD.5.b" -> "3.MD.6", 
   "3.MD.6" -> "3.MD.7a", "3.MD.7" -> "2.G.2", "3.MD.7" -> "5.NF.4b", 
   "3.MD.7a" -> "3.MD.7b", "3.MD.7a" -> "3.MD.7d", 
   "3.MD.7a" -> "5.NF.4b", "3.MD.7d" -> "3.MD.7c", 
   "3.MD.7d" -> "4.MD.3", "3.MD.8" -> "4.MD.3", "3.G.1" -> "5.G.3", 
   "3.G.2" -> "3.NF.1", "3.G.2" -> "3.MD.7a", "4.OA.1" -> "4.OA.2", 
   "4.OA.1" -> "5.NF.5.a", "4.OA.3" -> "6.EE.2a", 
   "4.OA.4" -> "6.NS.4", "4.OA.5" -> "5.OA.3", "4.NBT.1" -> "4.NBT.2",
    "4.NBT.1" -> "5.NBT.1", "4.NBT.2" -> "5.NBT.3", 
   "4.NBT.3" -> "5.NBT.4", "4.NBT.5" -> "5.NBT.5", 
   "4.NBT.5" -> "5.NF.4b", "4.NBT.6" -> "5.NBT.6", 
   "4.NBT.6" -> "5.NF.7a", "4.NF.1" -> "5.NF.1", 
   "4.NF.3a" -> "4.NF.3b", "4.NF.3a" -> "4.NF.3c", 
   "4.NF.3a" -> "4.NF.3d", "4.NF.3d" -> "5.NF.2", 
   "4.NF.4a" -> "4.NF.4b", "4.NF.4b" -> "4.NF.4c", 
   "4.NF.4c" -> "5.NF.6", "4.NF.5" -> "4.NF.6", "4.NF.6" -> "4.NF.7", 
   "4.NF.6" -> "7.NS.2d", "4.MD.1" -> "4.MD.2", "4.MD.2" -> "5.MD.1", 
   "4.MD.3" -> "6.G.1", "4.MD.4" -> "5.MD.2", "4.MD.4" -> "5.G.1", 
   "4.MD.5.a" -> "4.MD.5.b", "4.MD.5.b" -> "4.MD.6", 
   "4.MD.5.b" -> "4.G.1", "4.MD.6" -> "4.MD.7", "4.MD.6" -> "7.G.5", 
   "4.G.1" -> "4.G.2", "4.G.1" -> "7.G.2", "4.G.2" -> "5.G.3", 
   "5.OA.1" -> "5.OA.2", "5.OA.1" -> "6.EE.2b", "5.OA.3" -> "6.EE.9", 
   "5.NBT.1" -> "5.NBT.2", "5.NBT.2" -> "5.NBT.7", 
   "5.NBT.2" -> "6.EE.1", "5.NBT.6" -> "6.NS.2", 
   "5.NBT.7" -> "6.NS.3", "5.NF.1" -> "5.NF.2", "5.NF.3" -> "5.NF.4a",
    "5.NF.3" -> "5.NF.7a", "5.NF.3" -> "7.NS.2d", 
   "5.NF.4" -> "7.NS.2a", "5.NF.4a" -> "5.NF.4b", 
   "5.NF.5.a" -> "5.NF.5.b", "5.NF.7a" -> "5.NF.7b", 
   "5.NF.7b" -> "5.NF.7c", "5.NF.7b" -> "6.NS.1", 
   "5.MD.2" -> "6.SP.4", "5.MD.3a" -> "5.MD.3b", 
   "5.MD.3b" -> "5.MD.4", "5.MD.4" -> "5.MD.5a", 
   "5.MD.5a" -> "5.MD.5b", "5.MD.5b" -> "5.MD.5c", 
   "5.MD.5b" -> "6.G.2", "5.G.1" -> "5.G.2", "5.G.1" -> "6.NS.6b", 
   "5.G.2" -> "6.NS.8", "5.G.3" -> "5.G.4", "5.G.3" -> "7.G.3", 
   "5.G.4" -> "5.G.3", "6.RP.1" -> "6.RP.2", "6.RP.1" -> "6.RP.3c", 
   "6.RP.2" -> "6.RP.3a", "6.RP.2" -> "6.RP.3b", 
   "6.RP.2" -> "6.RP.3d", "6.RP.2" -> "7.RP.1", 
   "6.RP.3a" -> "7.RP.2a", "6.RP.3c" -> "7.RP.3", 
   "6.NS.1" -> "7.RP.1", "6.NS.1" -> "7.NS.2b", "6.NS.2" -> "6.NS.3", 
   "6.NS.3" -> "7.NS.2d", "6.NS.5" -> "6.NS.6a", 
   "6.NS.5" -> "6.NS.7b", "6.NS.5" -> "7.NS.1a", 
   "6.NS.6a" -> "6.NS.6b", "6.NS.6a" -> "6.NS.7c", 
   "6.NS.6b" -> "6.NS.6c", "6.NS.6c" -> "6.NS.7a", 
   "6.NS.6c" -> "6.NS.8", "6.NS.7b" -> "6.NS.7d", 
   "6.NS.7c" -> "6.NS.7d", "6.NS.7c" -> "6.NS.8", 
   "6.NS.7c" -> "7.NS.1b", "6.EE.1" -> "6.EE.2a", 
   "6.EE.1" -> "6.EE.2c", "6.EE.1" -> "6.EE.3", "6.EE.1" -> "6.EE.4", 
   "6.EE.1" -> "7.EE.3", "6.EE.1" -> "8.EE.1", "6.EE.2a" -> "6.EE.6", 
   "6.EE.2c" -> "6.EE.5", "6.EE.3" -> "6.EE.4", "6.EE.3" -> "7.EE.1", 
   "6.EE.3" -> "7.EE.2", "6.EE.4" -> "6.EE.3", "6.EE.5" -> "6.EE.7", 
   "6.EE.6" -> "6.EE.7", "6.EE.6" -> "6.EE.9", "6.EE.7" -> "6.EE.8", 
   "6.EE.7" -> "6.EE.9", "6.EE.7" -> "7.EE.4a", "6.EE.8" -> "6.EE.7", 
   "6.EE.8" -> "6.EE.9", "6.EE.8" -> "7.EE.4b", "6.EE.9" -> "6.EE.7", 
   "6.EE.9" -> "6.EE.8", "6.EE.9" -> "8.F.1", "6.G.1" -> "6.G.4", 
   "6.G.1" -> "7.G.1", "6.G.1" -> "7.G.4", "6.G.1" -> "8.G.6", 
   "6.G.2" -> "7.G.6", "6.G.3" -> "8.G.8", "6.G.4" -> "7.G.6", 
   "6.SP.1" -> "6.SP.2", "6.SP.1" -> "7.SP.1", "6.SP.2" -> "6.SP.3", 
   "6.SP.2" -> "6.SP.5a", "6.SP.2" -> "6.SP.5b", 
   "6.SP.3" -> "6.SP.5a", "6.SP.3" -> "6.SP.5b", 
   "6.SP.3" -> "6.SP.5c", "6.SP.3" -> "6.SP.5d", "6.SP.4" -> "6.SP.2",
    "6.SP.4" -> "6.SP.5d", "6.SP.4" -> "7.SP.3", "6.SP.4" -> "8.SP.1",
    "6.SP.5" -> "7.SP.3", "6.SP.5c" -> "7.SP.4", 
   "6.SP.5d" -> "7.SP.3", "7.RP.1" -> "7.RP.2a", 
   "7.RP.1" -> "7.RP.2b", "7.RP.1" -> "7.RP.2c", 
   "7.RP.2a" -> "7.RP.2d", "7.RP.2b" -> "7.RP.2d", 
   "7.RP.2c" -> "7.RP.3", "7.NS.1b" -> "7.NS.1c", 
   "7.NS.1c" -> "7.NS.1d", "7.NS.1d" -> "7.NS.3", 
   "7.NS.2a" -> "7.NS.2b", "7.NS.2b" -> "7.NS.2c", 
   "7.NS.2b" -> "7.NS.2d", "7.NS.2c" -> "7.NS.3", 
   "7.NS.2d" -> "8.NS.1", "7.EE.1" -> "7.EE.2", "7.EE.2" -> "7.EE.1", 
   "7.EE.4a" -> "8.EE.7a", "7.EE.4a" -> "8.EE.7b", "7.G.4" -> "8.G.9",
    "7.G.5" -> "8.G.5", "7.SP.1" -> "7.SP.2", "7.SP.2" -> "7.SP.4", 
   "7.SP.3" -> "7.SP.4", "7.SP.5" -> "7.SP.6", "7.SP.5" -> "7.SP.7a", 
   "7.SP.7a" -> "7.SP.7b", "7.SP.7b" -> "7.SP.8a", 
   "7.SP.7b" -> "7.SP.8c", "7.SP.8a" -> "7.SP.8b", 
   "8.NS.1" -> "8.NS.2", "8.EE.1" -> "8.EE.2", "8.EE.1" -> "8.EE.3", 
   "8.EE.3" -> "8.EE.4", "8.EE.5" -> "8.EE.6", "8.EE.5" -> "8.EE.8a", 
   "8.EE.5" -> "8.F.4", "8.EE.6" -> "8.EE.5", "8.EE.6" -> "8.EE.8a", 
   "8.EE.6" -> "8.F.4", "8.EE.7a" -> "8.EE.8a", 
   "8.EE.7b" -> "8.EE.8a", "8.EE.8a" -> "8.EE.8b", 
   "8.EE.8a" -> "8.EE.8c", "8.EE.8b" -> "8.EE.8a", 
   "8.EE.8b" -> "8.EE.8c", "8.EE.8c" -> "8.EE.8a", 
   "8.EE.8c" -> "8.EE.8b", "8.F.1" -> "8.F.2", "8.F.1" -> "8.F.3", 
   "8.F.1" -> "8.F.4", "8.F.1" -> "8.F.5", "8.F.4" -> "8.EE.5", 
   "8.F.4" -> "8.EE.6", "8.G.1" -> "8.G.3", "8.G.3" -> "8.G.2", 
   "8.G.3" -> "8.G.4", "8.G.6" -> "8.G.7", "8.G.6" -> "8.G.8", 
   "8.G.7" -> "8.G.6", "8.G.7" -> "8.G.8", "8.G.8" -> "8.G.6", 
   "8.G.8" -> "8.G.7", "8.SP.1" -> "8.SP.2", "8.SP.1" -> "8.SP.4", 
   "8.SP.2" -> "8.SP.3", "8.SP.2" -> "8.SP.4"};
```

and I would like to partition it into 9 directed columns corresponding to the ordering `k,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8`. I thought I can implement it using `MultipartiteEmbedding` once I know the `VertexPartitions`.

The `VertexPartitions` can be extracted from the edgelist. But I realized the `VertexList` does not follow the ordering. So I reordered after I did sort, i.e.

```
reorderedVertexList = Flatten[Drop[Prepend[sortVertexList, sortVertexList[[261 ;; 280]]],-20]]
```

Then I just manually counted how many nodes start with k, 1, 2, 3, etc. to identify the partitions. I got `"VertexPartition" -> {20, 21, 26, 35, 33, 34, 43, 37, 31}`.

When I put them together though:

```
newGraph = 
 Graph[reorderedVertexList, originalEdgeList, 
  GraphLayout -> {"MultipartiteEmbedding", 
    "VertexPartition" -> {20, 21, 26, 35, 33, 34, 43, 37, 31}}]
```

the graph does not show the partitions k,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8. I don't have 20 nodes for k, 21 nodes for "1" etc. Where did I get wrong? Appreciate the inputs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that the reason for the failure is that Mathematica always breaks the graph into components before computing a layout. After laying out each component separately, it combines them.

In this case, the partition sizes you provided won't be valid after breaking up the graph into components, therefore this procedure fails.

Thus the only way to do it is to supply vertex coordinates manually.

```
vertices = VertexList[originalEdgeList];
types = {"K", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8"};
partitions = Select[vertices, StringStartsQ[#]] & /@ types;

Graph[originalEdgeList, 
 VertexCoordinates -> Flatten@MapIndexed[#1 -> {10, 1} #2 &, partitions, {2}],
 EdgeStyle -> Arrowheads[Small],
 EdgeShapeFunction -> Arrow@*GraphElementData["CurvedArc"]]
```

[image]

Comment: Hi Szabolcs...you nailed it. Thanks a lot for the answer! I learned a couple of things along the way! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

**Outline**

```
Table[
  list[i] = 
   Select[originalEdgeList, 
    StringTake[#[[1]], 1] == ToString[i] &], {i, 9}];
```

This gives you eight sublists.

Get the vertexes with a "1" in the first position:

```
DeleteDuplicates[list[1][[All, 1]]]
```

(and likewise for the other 7 first digits).

Use `Length` to find how many in each "layer".

Then make `VertexCoordinates[1] = Table[{1, Length[list[1]]}]`, and likewise for the other layers.

Flatten your list to get a full list,

`myVertexCoordinates = Flatten[Union[VertexCoordinates[1],...,VertexCoordinates[8]]]`.

Use that in `Graph[originalEdgeList, myVertexCoordinates]`

Comment: Hi David, Thank you very much for your inputs! You have given me ideas on how to address it. Appreciate very much the help!